# Unable to Hide/Show "Enter Coupon" Section with CSS - SFRA Salesforce

Tags: css

Description:
I'm currently working on an SFRA (Salesforce B2C Commerce Storefront Reference Architecture) project and encountering difficulties while attempting to hide/show the "Enter coupon" section when the "Enter coupon code" link is clicked.

Background:
I have an ISML file containing the relevant code for rendering the "Enter coupon" section. Additionally, I have a CSS file that includes styles for hiding and showing elements based on the targeted section. I have successfully achieved the desired behavior using JavaScript and jQuery, but I'm now trying to accomplish the same result using CSS alone.

Code Snippet:
Here is the relevant code from the ISML file:

```
<div id="show">
    <iscomment> <a href="#show" id="promo-code-link" class="show">${Resource.msg('label.display.code', 'cart', null)}</a> </iscomment>
    <a href="#show" id="promo-code-link" class="show">Click here if you have a coupon code</a>
    <div id="promo-code-wrapper" class="hidden">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 d-sm-none">
                <p class="optional-promo">
                    <iscomment> ${Resource.msg('action.enter.promo.code', 'cart', null)}
                
                </iscomment>
                Enter promo code</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <form action="${pdict.actionUrls.submitCouponCodeUrl}" class="promo-code-form" method="GET"
                    name="promo-code-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="couponCode">${Resource.msg('label.promo.code', 'cart', null)}</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control coupon-code-field" id="couponCode"
                                    name="couponCode"
                                    placeholder="${Resource.msg('placholder.text.promo.code.input', 'cart', null)}" />
                                <div class="coupon-error">
                                    <span class="coupon-missing-error" id="missingCouponCode"
                                        role="alert">${Resource.msg('error.missing.coupon.code', 'cart', null)}</span>
                                    <span class="coupon-error-message" id="invalidCouponCode" role="alert"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="${pdict.csrf.tokenName}" value="${pdict.csrf.token}" />

                            <div class="col-5 promo-code-submit">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block promo-code-btn">
                                    ${Resource.msg('button.submit.promo.code', 'cart', null)}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant code from the CSS file:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

#promo-code-link {
    text-decoration: none;

    &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}

#content {
    display: none;
}
#show:target #promo-code-wrapper {
    display: block;
}
#show:target #promo-code-link {
    display: none;
}
```

Current Approach:
Currently, I'm attempting to use CSS to toggle the visibility of the "Enter coupon" section based on the state of the targeted element.

Expected Outcome:
I expect the "Enter coupon" section to be hidden by default, and when the "Enter coupon code" link is clicked, it should be displayed.

Issue:
Unfortunately, the section is not being hidden or shown as expected when clicking the link. I suspect there may be a problem with my CSS code.

Any help or guidance on achieving this behavior using CSS alone would be greatly appreciated. Alternatively, if there are any issues or improvements that can be made to the provided CSS code, please let me know. Thank you in advance
!